# How do I parse floats and doubles case-insensitively in c# (to cover "infinity", etc.)?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

In my locale, `double.Parse("Infinity")` returns `double.PositiveInfinity`, but `double.Parse("infinity")` throws `System.FormatException`. Analogous things happen for negative infinity and NaN.

I could obviously just use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol.Equals()` with a case-insensitive comparison to check for a match before calling `double.Parse()` (and do likewise for negative infinity and NaN). However, I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @Soner Mine happens to be en-US with a date format tweak, but I would like to support arbitrary CurrentCulture values.

Comment: Do you want to support the names of the current culture, so if it's "de-DE" `"+unendlich"` should be detected successfully as `PositiveInfinitySymbol`? It's not clear whether the input is controlled by you or not.

Comment: @Tim If the user's `CurrentCulture` is de-DE, I would like "+unendlich" (which _is_ `PositiveInfinitySymbol`) to parse successfully as `double.PositiveInfinity`. I would also like "+Unendlich" and "UNENDLICH" to parse to the same value.
The input is from a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much option beyond doing a [`TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and, on failure, special-casing the three special tokens as is shown in [`Number.ParseDouble()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#dbae9a94b8fcd241) and [`double.TryParse()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/double.cs.html#ea594ef6586a329e).  I'd do the check after rather than before since, in most cases, this won't happen.

Comment: Your reference links are convincing evidence there's no better way. I also like your suggestion of doing the rare case as a second effort instead of before the common path.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `Parse` method for double, it doesn't look like you have a lot of wiggle room:

```
// double
private static double Parse(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
{
    double result;
    try
    {
        result = Number.ParseDouble(s, style, info);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        string text = s.Trim();
        if (text.Equals(info.PositiveInfinitySymbol)) // case-sensitive comparison
        {
            result = double.PositiveInfinity;
        }
        else
        {
            if (text.Equals(info.NegativeInfinitySymbol)) // case-sensitive comparison
            {
                result = double.NegativeInfinity;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!text.Equals(info.NaNSymbol)) // case-sensitive comparison
                {
                    throw;
                }
                result = double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since the `Equals` method that is used here doesn't let you change case sensitiveness, I think that you should investigate in custom extensions for your parsing, perhaps adding a `AsDouble` method on top of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to support the names of the current culture, so if it's "de-DE" `"+unendlich"` should be detected successfully as `PositiveInfinitySymbol`? It's not clear whether the input is controlled by you or not.

You:

> If the user's `CurrentCulture` is "de-DE", I would like "+unendlich"
>   (which is `PositiveInfinitySymbol`) to parse successfully as
>   `double.PositiveInfinity`. I would also like "+Unendlich" and
>   "UNENDLICH" to parse to the same value.

Then your approach absolutely fine, isn't it? You could write a method like this:

```
public static bool ParseDoubleExt(string input, out double doubleVal, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, NumberFormatInfo nfi = null)
{
    if (nfi == null)
        nfi = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    doubleVal = double.MinValue;
    double d;

    if (double.TryParse(input, out d))
    {
        doubleVal = d;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        bool isPosInf = nfi.PositiveInfinitySymbol.Equals(input, comparison);
        if (isPosInf)
        {
            d = double.PositiveInfinity;
            return true;
        }
        bool isNegInf = nfi.NegativeInfinitySymbol.Equals(input, comparison);
        if (isNegInf)
        {
            d = double.NegativeInfinity;
            return true;
        }
        bool isNAN = nfi.NaNSymbol.Equals(input, comparison);
        if (isNAN)
        {
            d = double.NaN;
            return true;
        }

        // to be extended ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

and use it in this way:

```
string doubleStr = "+UNENDLICH";
double d;
bool success = ParseDoubleExt(doubleStr, out d);
```